# Symfony2 and Doctrine: OneToMany relation duplicates data in the table

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have two tables: articles and emails.
The emails table will contain emails related to the specific articles, for example:

```
id    |  article_id |     email
1     |      1      |  test@etest.com
2     |      1      |  test2@test.com
3     |      2      |  test@etest.com
4     |      2      |  test3@test.com
```

Etc....

There is a relation between article_id and the id from the articles table.

In my entity, I have this code:

```
class Articles
{ 
    ....
     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Emails", mappedBy="articles")
      */
      private $emails_rel; 

    ...
}

class Emails
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Articles", inversedBy="emails_rel", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $articles; 
}
```

In my controller, i am doing some tests where I will persist or not some entities.
At  the end, I am doing a flush

```
$em->flush();
```

And the strange behaviour is that in my Emails table, the data is duplicated as soon as I am doing the flush. When testing the entity manager with

```
$em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()
```

I am getting an empty array.

Any idea why? Thank you very much.

EDIT:

Here is the test:

```
$articl = new Articles();
$articl = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Articles p WHERE p.bMailToMatch = 1")->getResult();
$nb = count($articl);

// BECAUSE I WILL WORK WITH A LOTS OF ENTRIES - PREVENT MEMORY OVERFLOW
$em->clear();    

if(isset( $articl )) {
    foreach($articl as $i => $art) {
        $array_emails = null;

        $art_emails = $art->getEmailsRel();
        foreach ($art_emails as $e) {
            $array_emails[] = $e->getEmail();
        }

        $art_id = $art->getId ();
        echo "\n\n---------- $i ----------\n " . $art->getDoi ();

        // TAKES ARTICLE WITH ZERO EMAIL
        if (!isset($array_emails) ) {
            $updated_article = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Articles')->findOneBy(array( 'id' => ($art_id)    )) ; 
            // Because of the clearing of the entity manager
            echo"\n\n$art_id Article DOI \n".$updated_article->getDoi();
            echo "\n==>Put the BMailToMatch's flag to 0";
            $updated_article->setBMailToMatch(0);
            $em->persist($updated_article);
        }
        else {
            echo " ==> ok\n";
        }

        if (($i % 3) == 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
    }

    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
}

return new Response ( "\n\nFinished!!\n" );
```

Comment: Could you put the code you're testing with ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel, I uploaded the code from my controller

Comment: Does it work if you remove `$em->clear();` from everywhere? Also why you just dont make one `update` query, example `UPDATE Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Articles p SET p.bMailToMatch = 0 WHERE p.emails_rel IS EMPTY`

Comment: Could you specify what you mean with duplicated?

Comment: What is this if statement for? `if (($i % 3) == 0) {` Why would you want only flush and clear every third iteration?

Comment: PS: After deleting my own answer two times I would be very interested in solving this know. :)

Comment: Just like @JimMartens said, please specify what you mean by duplicate data. Are you talking about the same email "test@etest.com" showing up multiple times in the email table? Take a closer look at your relationships: Does each article can only have one email or multiple? Does each email can only have one or multiple articles? Also it seems like you are trying to do bulk inserts (correct me if I'm wrong) and you are making multiple queries to get an extra object `$updated_article` you already have `$art`, this logic in addition to flushes every `i%3==0` could cause some 'unexpected' behavior.

Comment: Maybe instead of `clear`, detach the already processed articles from the entity manager after every flush. Clear simply removes references from Doctrine ORM to your entities, but you still have the objects in the array.

Comment: Hi Milos, if my answer is correct, may you award me in order I receive the bounty ? Thank you and happy new year :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't caught your problem before I reproduced it but now it's a kind of obvious.
Your problem comes from the use of the clear method.
Actually, if you clear your entity manager, it forgets their existence and will persist them as new ones.

If you have performance issue, you can limit the number of items you deal with and do it recursively until you're done.

I hope it helped you ;)

Good Luck

Cheers

Comment: thats what i saw when i read the clear call. AFAIK doctrine keeps the mapping of the object to a database record in the entitity manager (so it doesnt check the id in the table everytime). So if you clear the em, every object you have will seem to be new

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading this correctly then a simplified version of the code would be as follows:

```
$articles_with_mail_to_match_true = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Articles p WHERE p.bMailToMatch = 1")->getResult();

foreach($articles_with_mail_to_match_true as $i => $article_with_mail_to_match_true) 
{
    if ( count($article_with_mail_to_match_true->getEmailsArray()) < 1 ) 
    {
        $article_copy_object = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Articles')->findOneBy(array( 'id' => ($article_with_mail_to_match_true->getId()) )) ; 

        $article_copy_object->setBMailToMatch(0);

        $em->persist($article_copy_object);
    }

    if (($i % 3) == 0) {
        $em->flush();
    }
}

$em->flush();
```

It seems the only thing you are persisting is the $article_copy_object after changing the the one value. If that is the case then either A. there is something wrong in your entity we can not see in this code example or B. it is happening elsewhere and not during this operation.